# SQL OrderBY throwing error

Tags: sql, join, sql-order-by, attunity

I am currently working on three tables where , I need to orderby based on two columns which are part of two different table  . Where as I need to JOIN three table to extract the resulted output.

For eg my query is as below .

```
select TableA.*,TableC.call1, TableB.column1, TableB.column2, TableB.column3 from TableA, TableB, TableC
where (TableA.PART_IND = TableB.PART_IND )
and (TableA.PART_IND = TableC.PART_IND )
and (TableA.MM = '03')
order by TableA.MAR , TableB.column2 ;
```

Here Table3.column3 is part of the TableB and when I try to add TableB.column2 in the order by I am getting error and when I check the error it states SORT_mergeProblem .

If I add any the columns of TableB in order by , I am getting error , where as if I dont refer any columns from TableB in the OrderBy it works fine .  Can you please let me know what is wrong , in this query ..

When we use OrderBy in more than 2 tables , do we need to consider anything specifically  ?

```
Attunity Error log

[2016-03-07T07:27:40.066];  Requesting process has no current process transaction identifier.; error: invalid block length
specified.
[2016-03-07T07:27:40.070]; [A072] SRT_Initmerge : SRT failed  SORT_MERGE PROBLEM= 3
```